# In phonegap build if i am using onesignal-cordova-plugin and cordova-plugin-googlemaps while build it is showing error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, onesignal

In phonegap build if i am using onesignal-cordova-plugin and cordova-plugin-googlemaps while build it is showing error for spec

```
<gap:plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin"         source="npm"    spec="2.4.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" source="npm" spec="2.3.6">
    <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="API_KEY" />
</plugin>
```

ERROR:

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.StreetViewSource;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class StreetViewSource
  location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model
/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
          StreetViewSource source = "OUTDOOR".equals(cameraOpts.getString("source")) ?
          ^
  symbol:   class StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama
/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
              ^
  symbol:   variable StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama
/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:88: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable StreetViewSource
  location: class PluginStreetViewPanorama
/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:280: error: cannot find symbol
              StreetViewSource source = "OUTDOOR".equals(cameraOpts.getString("source")) ?
              ^
  symbol: class StreetViewSource
/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                  StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                  ^
  symbol: variable StreetViewSource
/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginStreetViewPanorama.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                  StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR : StreetViewSource.DEFAULT;
                                             ^
  symbol: variable StreetViewSource
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
7 errors
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed
Error: /gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
```

If i changed my cordova-plugin-googlemaps specification to spec="2.2.9" Its working but i need cordova-plugin-googlemaps specification greater than 2.2.9,
Is there any way to overcome this issue.

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, For me GPS is more important than Notification so i have removed that  plugin **onesignal-cordova-plugin**

Comment: Thanks. I will keep researching. If I find the solution I'll be sure to update here.